# Bootstrap with Angular 2+

Tags: html, angular, button, sass, bootstrapping

Im trying to use a primary button from bootstrap in my Angular module. But it seems to not work.

Heres what I've done so far.

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

Added bootstrap module and imports.

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),...]

exports: [BsDropdownModule, TooltipModule, ModalModule]
```

Now in the Module I use this code for a button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

but the button is still the standard html button. Not a blue submit button. Did I forget any steps when importing bootstrap. In the node_modules structure I can find bootstrap in there with the necessary .js and .css files.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import modules, instead you need to attach styles from bootstrap. `import` them in the `styles.css` file or configure in the `styles` section of the `angular.json` file

```
"styles": [
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
]
```

or your relative/absolute path

Comment: Added it to the styles in the .angular-cli.json. Something is still missing :/

Comment: In the browser inspect your element, maybe another style with `!important` is applied

Comment: I checked everything. Does not seem to work. I found 1 !important though.: `-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;` but i don't think that this will be the reason its faulty. All  3 basically gave me the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in your case bootstrap is just about styling. Pure CSS styling of your HTML elements. Ngx-bootstrap it is about Angular components(the way you are decomposing your application). It's just like regular bootstrap with a jquery for interactivity but in an Angular world.

To get just bootstrap styles in your application you need to run command:

```
    npm install bootstrap
```

Then put these source files into angular-cli.json:

```
    "styles": [
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ]
```

And rebuild you project.

Answer (score 0):

We have two options to import the CSS from Bootstrap that was installed from NPM. One by **configuring in angular.json** and second by **importing directly in src/style.css or src/style.scss**. You can go through this https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/#3-importing-the-css and learn more about how to do that.